# Increment a variable in a .txt file with bash

Tags: bash, sed

I'm trying to change a variable in a .txt file but I can't figure how. I've looked on internet and tried what was written but it doesn't work. I get the following error message :

> sed: 1: "abc.txt": command a expects \ followed by text

Here was what I originally tried to run:

```
sed -i 's/Hi/Good Morning/' abc.txt
```

Comment: Can you provide partial content of `abc.txt`? I'm not able to reproduce.

Comment: it's just something to help me learn bash so was something like " Hi, how are you"

Comment: Unfortunately without being able to reproduce the problem we can't help you. Consider running the sommand again and see if it gives the same error message.

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this with the same error on Mac OS X. What's happening is that `sed` is taking `'s/Hi/Good Morning/'` to be the argument to `-i`, and then considering `abc.txt` to be the `sed` command itself.

Answer (score 2):

Check your man page for sed. `-i` probably requires a suffix argument.

> -i extension
>
> Edit files in-place, saving backups with the specified extension.  If a zero-length extension is given,
>                no backup will be saved.  It is not recommended to give a zero-length extension when in-place editing
>                files, as you risk corruption or partial content in situations where disk space is exhausted, etc.

What's happening is that sed is taking `'s/Hi/Good Morning/'` to be the argument to `-i`, and then considering `abc.txt` to be the sed command itself.

By adding a proper backup extension to the command, it will work like so:

```
$ cat abc.txt
Hi, How are you

$ sed -i .bak 's/Hi/Good Morning/' abc.txt

$ cat abc.txt
Good Morning, How are you

$ cat abc.txt.bak
Hi, How are you
```